# Doubt about derivatives in complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Actually, I had this existential doubt while working in my homework. It's obvious that, if I have a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $z_0$, then $$ \dfrac{f(z_n) - f(z_0)}{z_n - z_0} \longrightarrow f'(z_0)  \quad \text{as} \,\, n \rightarrow \infty$$

What is not quite obvious for me, but seems reasonable at least, is that if I have two sequences  $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{w_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, both converging to $z_0$, then
$$ \dfrac{f(z_n) - f(w_n)}{z_n - w_n} \longrightarrow f'(z_0)  \quad \text{as} \,\, n \rightarrow \infty$$

I have had some bad times trying to prove this bounding differences (I am pretty bad bounding ._.), so I was unable to draft a proof.
Thanks in advance for your lecture, and more thanks for your answers. And sorry for the probable mistakes my English can have.

FAQ: 
-Is this your Homework?

-Nope,just a random idea that came out while doing it.

-Are you talking in complex variable?

-Well, I was doing my homework of complex calculus, but I'm sure that the reasoning is pretty much the same in real calculus.

Comment: For differentiable functions of a real variable, it is not true. Differentiable functions of a complex variable are much better-behaved.

Comment: Not even for smooth functions? Do you have a counter-example in mind?

Comment: Yes, one based on $x^2\sin(1/x)$ near $x=0$. Definitely not smooth, the derivative is not continuous at $0$, but exists.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(z_n)-f(w_n)}{z_n-w_n}&=
\frac{f(z_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-w_n}+\frac{f(w_n)-f(z_0)}{w_n-z_n}\\
&=\frac{f(z_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-z_0}\frac{z_n-z_0}{z_n-w_n}+
\frac{f(w_n)-f(z_0)}{w_n-z_0}\frac{w_n-z_0}{w_n-z_n}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (*)
\end{align*}

Now
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_n-z_0}{z_n-w_n}&=1-\frac{w_n-z_0}{w_n-z_n}\;\;\;\;\;\;(**)
\end{align*}
Now's clear that
$$
\exists\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{z_n-z_0}{z_n-w_n}
\Longleftrightarrow
\exists\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{w_n-z_0}{w_n-z_n}
$$
Assuming these limits exists (check it), their value will be the same (check it too!). Call it $\alpha\in\mathbb C$, and by (**) you'll have $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally it's clear that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(z_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-z_0}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(w_n)-f(z_0)}{w_n-z_0}=
f'(z_0)
$$
and by (*) you can conclude your conjecture is correct.

Comment: @Mark: does this answer satsify you?